# Python: how to remove duplicates from a list using a set (order is important)

Tags: python, list, set

so I have this list: `a = [-11, 13, 13, 10, -11, 10, 9, -3, 6, -9, -6, -6, 13, 8, -11, -5, 6, -8, -12, 5, -9, -1, -5, 2, -2, 13, 14, -9, 7, -4]`

and by using a set I need to remove the duplicates and also keep them in the same order

I used this code:

```
def unique(a):
    a = set(a)
    return list(a)
```

it does remove the duplicates when I use it but the problem is it returns them in numerical order like this:

```
>>> unique(a)
[-2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, -12, -11, -9, -8, -6, -5, -4, -3, -1]
```

how can I return it in the same order as the original list while removing duplicates using sets?

EDIT:

so I've used this code because it worked:

```
def unique(a):
    seen = set()
    return [seen.add(x) or x for x in a if x not in seen]
```

but can someone explain to me what it does? because I need to make another once but it returns the list without negative numbers, and I can't do that unless I understand what that code does

Comment: The fact that this question is marked as Duplicate is ironic.

Answer (score 5):

This function already exists in the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes), as `unique_everseen`. You can copy and paste it from there, or read it to see how it works, or install the third-party package `more-itertools` and use it from there.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
def unique_everseen(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for element in iterable:
        if element not in seen:
            seen.add(element)
            yield element
```

---

The version in the recipes allows for a `key` function, which you don't need, and it has two optimizations. But first understand the simple version:

`seen` is a set of all values seen so far. For each value, we check whether it's in `seen`. If so, we skip it. Otherwise, we add it to the set and `yield` it. So, we `yield` each element only the first time it's seen.

---

The first optimization in the recipe version is simple: looking up the `seen.add` method isn't quite free, so we do it once instead of N times, by doing `seen_add = seen.add`. This makes a sizable difference when benchmarking trivial cases, like a list of small integers; it may not make much difference in real use cases with values that are more expensive to hash.

The second optimization is to use `ifilterfalse` instead of an `if` to skip over the elements that have already been seen. Basically this means that if you have N elements and M unique elements, you only do M iterations in Python and N in the optimized C code inside `ifilterfalse`, instead of doing N in Python. Since iterating in C is much faster, this is worth it unless almost all of your elements are unique.

---

To make it work with a `key` function, all you have to do is keep a set of `key(element)` values seen so far, instead of `element` values seen so far. This makes the `ifilterfalse` optimization a little harder to do and much less effective, so it isn't done.

---

If you're only dealing with sequences, not arbitrary iterables, and you can count on Python 2.7+, there's another way to do this which is almost as efficient, and even simpler:

```
def unique(a):
    return OrderedDict.fromkeys(a).keys()
```

Answer (score 2):

Abuse of list comprehension:

```
def unique(seq):
    seen = set()
    return [seen.add(x) or x for x in seq if x not in seen]
    # or use parentheses instead of brackets above for a generator
```

Comment: `seen.add` always returns `None`, so this will not work.

Comment: After the edit, it does work, but it's still pretty horrible. Using `or` to sequence two operations in an expression is even more of an abuse than using a list comprehension for side effects.

Comment: Actually, you can remove the listcomp abuse by just putting the `add` in the condition: `[x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]`. But it's still an abuse of `seen.add`, and possibly even harder to see that way…

Comment: I feel like `set` could really use a method that adds an item and returns a Boolean indicating whether the item actually needed to be added. Then you could just do e.g. `[x for x in seq if seen.did_add(x)]`

Comment: Almost none of the built-in types' methods mutate but return a value… but one of the few exceptions, `dict.setdefault`, isn't too far away from your suggested `set.did_add`, so maybe it's reasonable.